# Set computer name when starting an instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, papertrail-app

I'm using a windows AMI to start an instance that is hosting a java application. I'm using papertrail for logging which uses the name of the computer to display the system associated with a log stream. Right now computer's name is an auto-generated value, but I want to give it a specific value. How can I do this?

Setting the name on the AMI is not an option since I'm using the same AMI to launch a number of instances that all must have different computer names.

**Conclusion**

In the end, since my main concern was to change the name for papertrail's sake, I can do that via http://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/java-logback-logging/
Thank you all for your help

Comment: instance hostname or ec2 tag's Name?

Comment: [This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#user-data-execution) might help

Comment: @BMW Instance hostname

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. First disable the "Set Computer name" option. More details here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/UsingConfig_WinAMI.html
(Look for "To change settings using the Ec2 Service Properties dialog box" section).

Then configure the AMI to rename the instance.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#user-data-execution

If you want different names for the computer, then use a shell script to generate the computer name.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a powershell userdata script

```
<powershell>
Rename-Computer -NewName foo -Force
Restart-Computer
</powershell>
```

However, this means it may be some minutes prior to after ASG starts instance that instance is really ready and will have a reboot in there too which can cause problems.